# How to call void method in different class?

Tags: java, void

```
public class Equation {
    public static void quadEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
        double solution1 = (-b + (Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))/(2 * a));
        double solution2 = (-b - (Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))/(2 * a));    
    }
}
```

I have to print **solution1** and **soltion2** at different class(tester) by calling them.

It is a `void` method call, so it doesn't returning anything.

In this case how can I call them in tester?

Homework assignment! It is just part of my homework so you guys can freely help this one

I solved it! Thanks for those of you helped me :)

Comment: You need to change the return type.

Comment: but I have to keep the void

Comment: The shown `void` method does not make any sense. It calculates something, assigns the results to local variables, but does nothing else with these variables. This method can be deleted without changing any behavior. So, what exactly do you want to test?

Comment: I have to find two real roots of quadratic formula. I input the number at tester class and it is calculated at this class. And I have to printout two real roots by calling them.

Comment: Sticking to this requirement explanation does not help. As I told you, this method does not make any sense. So, first thing is to change it. Additionally, I asked you, what exactly do you want to test. You didn't answer that also. You should help us to help you ...

Comment: "but I have to keep the void" => Why?

Comment: tester is just driver

Comment: it is school homework.

Comment: @Evelyn You can call this method like any other static method. In this case you can write `Equation.quadEquation(2, 3, 5);`. But the variables `solution1` and `solution2` are local variables inside this method and can only be used inside that method. You might want to [edit] your question to include the homework assignment. Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @Evelyn one more thing to consider, your method is static, which means you won't invoke it on the *instance*, rather you'll invoke it like `ClassName.methodName();`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I did that one at tester(driver) class

Comment: @Evelyn and? I hope you resolved your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you call a `static void` method in another class.

== file exercise/Equation.java ==

```
package exercise;

public class Equation {
    public static void quadEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
        double solution1 = (-b + (Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))/(2 * a));
        double solution2 = (-b - (Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))/(2 * a));  

        // If you want to print the solutions, add some print 
        // statements here!
    }
}
```

== file OtherClass.java ==

```
import exercise.Equation;

public class OtherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Equation.quadEquation(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);  // calls the method in Equation
    }
}
```

You should be able to compile and run the above from the command line as follows.

```
$ # change directory to directory containing "OtherClass.java"
$ javac -cp . exercise/Equation.java OtherClass.java 
$ java -cp . OtherClass
```

The key things are:

1. If you want to use `Equation` in another class, it is best if you declare  the class in a Java package.
2. Then you needs to `import` the `Equation` into the other class.  (This is not necessary if both classes are in the same package.)
3. Obviously a `void` method cannot return anything.  So if you want some output you from your `quadEquation` method, then the method needs to print it itself.

Note that the approach described in the previous point is *typically* a pour design choice.  You *typically* don't want to mix the "concerns" of the code like that.  You typically want to treat the calculation and outputting the results as separate problems.  For example, you may want your `quadEquation` method to be usable in contexts where you output the solution or solutions somewhere else ... or not at all.

Other things:

- If this is supposed to find the roots of a quadratic equation, you have not coded the formula correctly.  There should be a "square root" in there; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula.
- You also need to consider the case where the solutions are imaginary numbers.  (Unless you have been told to ignore that ...)
- I see that you have commented to say that the other class is a driver.  This may make the above example invalid.  You are going to have to read the code of the driver class (or the description of the class) top work out how it is going to call your class.  It may well be that the problem of calling your `quadEquation` *has been solved for you* by your teacher.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learn about package yet so that's why I was confused